# Firebase - Get user id of the user who just performed an operation on the database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

After pushing an item to a certain list in Firebase, I'd like to use `update` to add a `createdBy` property on the newly created item. This property should be the UID of the logged in user, but I'm unsure how to get it without storing it when I first log in.

Is it possible to get it somehow without doing the above?

**Note that I do not want the key of `event`**.

This is what I want:

```
let ref = this.af.database.list('/events');

ref.push(eventCopy).then((event) => {

  const uuid: string = theUserWhoJustPushed.uuid;

  ref.update(event.key(), {createdBy: uuid});
});
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication users have a UID, not a UUID. You might want to update your vocabulary to prevent confusion. Aside from that, have you tried `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`? (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I could've sworn they changed it to UUID like 1-2 years ago? Or did they change from UUID? Anyway I'll try that.

Comment: The format of the value was changed (multiple times already). But the property is (and always was) called a User ID and abbreviated to UID.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better if you create service to do that. In this service's constructor you would get user is by subscribing the firebase auth.